# Update single data row from table to another

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How can I **update a complete data row by using a data row from another table**.

Example:

```
Table A

ID   |   NAME    |   ...   |
----------------------------
 1   |   Test    |   ...   |
 2   |   Test2   |   ...   |



Table B

ID   |   NAME    |   ...   |
----------------------------
 1   |   Test97  |   ...   |
```

So I want to copy the content of a single row of Table B to Table A and override existing values. I do not want to name all columns. The contents of table A and B are redundant.

**Summarize:**
I want an equivalent to the following INSERT Statement as an UPDATE Statement:

```
INSERT INTO destTable 
VALUES  (SELECT * FROM TABLE2)
FROM srcTable
```

Any hint, even telling me that its not possible, is very appricated.

Comment: Maybe you can first delete row you want to update, and then use the insert with the select? I understand this is a workaround, of course. I'm not aware of an update with select statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can update a set of columns (you still have to list the columns once):

```
SQL> UPDATE table_a
  2     SET (ID, NAME, etc)
  3         = (SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE table_b.id = table_a.id)
  4   WHERE table_a.id IN (SELECT ID FROM table_b);

1 row updated
```

Comment: Exactly what I put, but much cleaner and nicer :o)

Comment: Yes, I thought that there might be another way to do it. But it is ok for me that way. Thanks Ardman and Thanks Vincent.

Comment: You can't use the SELECT * unless the table structure of table_b is exactly like the SET list; you'll probably have to list the fields in the SELECT

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
UPDATE suppliers  
SET supplier_name = ( SELECT customers.name
FROM customers
WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id) 
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT customers.name
    FROM customers
    WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to name each column. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If the columns are the same, then I believe you can just do:
UPDATE tableA
  FROM tableB
 WHERE etc.

Comment: Can't upvote anymore (value too old to be changed...). Sorry for that. Would like to upvote...

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an Oracle MERGE statement.  With this statement, it inserts if a match doesn't exist and updates if it already exists.

[Here](http://www.psoug.org/reference/merge.html) is a site with an example.

```
MERGE INTO bonuses b
USING (
  SELECT employee_id, salary, dept_no
  FROM employee
  WHERE dept_no =20) e
ON (b.employee_id = e.employee_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET b.bonus = e.salary * 0.1
  DELETE WHERE (e.salary < 40000)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (b.employee_id, b.bonus)
  VALUES (e.employee_id, e.salary * 0.05)
  WHERE (e.salary > 40000);
```

Comment: The only trick to this is that you have to explicitly list your columns in the UPDATE statement which it sounds like you don't want to do.